# Deploy Spring boot app jar file embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, spring-boot, remote-server

I have an Spring boot application which i want to deploy to a remote linux server via Jenkins. i want to use embedded tomcat. I succeed to start the application manually.
I am thinking to use ssh to copy the jar file after it built by maven.
What i need to do is the following

- stop the running jar file on remote server
- overwrite the existing jar file or delete it and copy the new file from Jenkins workspace
- Start the new jar file.

Is there any jenkins plugin to do this automatically. If not could someone help me or point me to guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Publish over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) will help you.

[This tutorial](https://caffinc.github.io/2015/05/automatically-updating-fat-jar-with-jenkins-publish-over-ssh/) describes exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a shell script that can do that, Jenkins has a place holder for sell code to be executed after a successful build. But I would suggest taking a look at docker and EBS(aws elastic bean stalk) because you can to what you want without any down time in a less hackie fashion. I have a similar scenario as the one you are explaining but I use docker, EBS and the amazon command line interface to do so.